# Lost Ubuntu 18.04 packages due to libwayland

Tags: nvidia, package-management, dependencies, restore, reset

In order to fix some driver nvidia gpu issue with steam, I tried installing libwayland as suggested in a forum,
`sudo apt-get install libwayland-client0:i386`. Now I was running a 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and while the installation was going on, I noticed that it started removing packages. By the time it finished, it removed a bunch of packages, and now i dont even have vim or nautilus installed. I am still not sure what libwayland does, and what it replaced in the original Ubuntu 18.04. I just want back my applications which come with the default ubuntu installation. I tried following instructions to fix broken ubuntu installation in https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-broken-ubuntu-os-without-reinstalling-it/  but running `sudo apt install -f` just shows me a list of packages that are no longer required and suggests that I remove them with autoremove.

Any suggestions on how to restore my Ubuntu? I still have access to my data and the desktop environment but I don't think tracking down every package that comes with 18.04 and installing with apt-get is a feasible option.

[Update]
I checked the file in /var/log/apt and it had a huge list of the packages that were removed, including basic packages like gedit etc. I have the list, but is there any way to reinstall all these without doing them 1-by-1 manually?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS3YR.png)

Comment: checked ```/etc/log/apt```, was empty

Comment: Sorry, it's /var/log/apt Apologies.